# prioritized queue while preventing stravation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, priority-queue

Here's my problem:
I have thousands of sensors to poll. Each sensor has a polling interval (not fixed, but rather changing over time).

So I need to poll them one after one, efficiently.
For that cause, I could use a priority queue (with poll-timestamps as keys).

The problem is that sensors could be neglected:
For example, if there's a sensor which needs be polled every 15 minutes and there are plenty of sensors need to be polled every 5 minutes then the priority queue could favor them over the first one.

So I could use few priority-queues instead of one, but the question of how to pick the next sensor to poll, remains.

What could be an ideal solution to my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use queue? When it's time for someone to be polled add them to the queue.

Comment: @Zar, that would be horrible - I need to poll them at the right time (or at least getting close to it as much as possible). It is worth mentioning polling takes few seconds on average, for each sensor.

Comment: Order the priority queue by next required poll time. Every time you poll the sensor remove it from the queue and update the next time it needs to be polled. Then re-add it to the queue

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.  The only way the 15-minute sensor could *not* be polled when its next polling time comes is if an infinite stream of other polling requests are scheduled for *earlier* times -- but that can't happen.

Comment: @flkes, sensors never get out of the queue (the key should be updated though)

Comment: Yes, but if you add them to the queue when it's time for them to be queued they'll already be in order? As in the one at the top of the queue will be the one who's timer went off first. Unless I'm you're prioritizing them in some other way. Add them to the queue when they need to be polled and remove them once they've been polled.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I agree that a sensor could not be starved (it's time will come) though if there plenty of 5-minute sensors, the 15-minutes one would be delayed.

Comment: Use a scheduling library such as [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), create triggers for when the polling of each sensor should occur, define a pool of how many you want to run in parallel, and Quartz will figure it out for you.

Comment: @Zar, sensors don't get out of the queue, but rather their keys get updated.

Comment: Will there actually be delays?  That can only happen if too many polls are scheduled within a short time interval.  But even in that case: Why do you expect the 15-minute ones to be delayed, instead of the 5-minute ones?

Comment: @Elimination First, a `PriorityQueue` doesn't have "keys". Second, you cannot just update the priority value of an element in the queue. You have to remove it, change the value, then re-add it.

Comment: Can you not just make another queue to keep track of which sensors need to be polled, then add/remove them from that as needed?

Comment: @Andreas: A priority queue (heap) in CS *does* have keys.  Presuming that `PriorityQueue` is the name of a Java class implementing this well-known data structure, it must have something corresponding to keys.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The Java  [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) orders elements according to their *natural ordering* (i.e. using the elements own [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) method), or by a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) provided at queue construction time. Elements don't have separate keys.

Comment: @Andreas: Then the "key" is whatever `compareTo()` or the supplied `Comparator` internally checks to decide what answer to return.  That doesn't have to be something explicitly stored in a separate field -- it could be something computed from the data itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the scheduled polling time as the priority, you might not be able to keep up with polling, but you won't have a starvation problem where some sensors are never polled.

Java's [`DelayQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) is a good fit for this. Store the scheduled time in the [`Delayed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html) instance (based on `System.nanoTime()`), and then implement `getDelay()` to compute the difference between that and the current `System.nanoTime()`.

Because `DelayedQueue` is a concurrent queue, multiple consumers can take tasks and run them, and reschedule new tasks independently. This will help keep up with the load and maintain your schedule, because while a slow sensor is being polled, another thread can be waiting for the next task to become eligible for execution.

Suppose you have a two sensors: sensor A that is polled every second, and sensor B that is polled every 3 seconds, and queue that is ordered by scheduled polling time.

```
time 0: A polled, rescheduled for time 1
        B polled, rescheduled for time 3
time 1: A polled, rescheduled for time 2
time 2: A polled, rescheduled for time 3
time 3: A polled, rescheduled for time 4
        B polled, rescheduled for time 6
```

The order of polling at time 3 isn't determinate, but B will definitely get its turn for polling before any sensors scheduled at time 4.

---

From an OP comment:

> sensors don't get out of the queue, but rather their keys get updated

Then you are doing it wrong. A priority queue doesn't have keys, but if they did, they wouldn't support key mutation.

A queue is a collection to which producers add elements, and from which consumers remove elements. If its contents aren't changing, use a different collection.

---

If there are times when there's too much work to do everything on schedule, you have two fundamental options: do everything, and accept that some will be late, or skip some work, in order to complete the most important tasks in a timely manner. Which is appropriate depends on your application, but the first approach is fragile in the sense that you might never catch up.

### Do everything late

If you have to do all the work, but don't care when, you might use two priorities. The first is a schedule, as described already. The second is an "importance" metric, which is used to prioritize tasks that are ready for execution.

A small number of worker threads, maybe just one, consume the `DelayedQueue`, waiting for tasks based on their schedule. However, instead of executing the task directly, these workers simply put tasks into another `BlockingQueue` based on their importance. A larger pool of workers consumes this queue, executing the most important tasks first.

If the average load is greater than the available capacity, this queue will continue to grow. Otherwise, all the work will be done eventually, and you can devise any policy you like to prioritize tasks once they are ready to execute.

### Do something on time

It may be that a late sample is worthless, and it would be better to skip polling rather than get further behind. In that case, a "grace period" could be specified for each task. When it comes out of the `DelayQueue`, check to see whether the current time is within the grace period for execution. If so, go ahead and execute the task. Otherwise, discard the task and get the next. The grace period may be a function of the polling frequency, with longer periods having a longer grace period, while skipping high frequency tasks helps clear the queue quickly without missing samples for long periods.

### Hybrid

You can combine the "grace period" idea with the first approach, giving the most important tasks the best chance to be executed on time, but skipping tasks when its too late for them to be useful in order to catch up.

### Single-threading

All of these strategies are still useful with a single thread executing tasks, but staying on schedule is a pretty tall order when one thread is serially executing relatively long-running tasks like polling a physical sensor.

Even if the processor is single-core and only executes one thread at a time, it will still support thread scheduling through context-switching so that progress can be made on another task while others are blocked on I/O. This will do a much better job of preserving the desired schedule.

Comment: I assume your processing thread(s) would use `take()`, so they sleep while waiting for new polling events? That would work, but using a scheduling library, such as `Quartz`, would allow those threads to do other work while waiting, reducing the total number of threads needed by the app. Downside is of course that polling now competes with other jobs for the threads. Upside is that you can limit the total number of threads running in parallel for all jobs. Which is best is a design decision.

Comment: That sounds awesome (wasn't familiar with that type of queue) but consider a case where a 15-minutes sensor need to be polled for the first time at 00:15 but there are plenty of 5-minutes sensors which scheduled to 00:14:59 - The first sensor would be temporarily starved. Isn't it?

Comment: @Andreas I would never suggest using Quartz as a way to conserve resources, but yes, in general, it could be helpful in some systems to allow the worker threads to process tasks from other producers.

Comment: @erickson : ConcurrentSkipListSet with DelayedElement could be an option as well for better performance.

Comment: @Elimination If your system is beefy enough to allocate enough threads to handle all the 14:59 tasks + 1, the task at 15:00 will run on time. If your system is not fast enough, then nothing can help you. It's not a scheduling or starvation issue, it's a capacity problem.

Comment: @Rishi In practice, I feel like it's easier to consume the `DelayedQueue`. With `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, its easy to unconditionally consume the "first" element, but if that element is a `Delayed`, it's hard to atomically check whether it is eligible for execution according to its schedule *and* consume it. How would you approach that?

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's a capacity problem (and scaling could help solving it) but it's an ordering issue as well. Isn't it? You could use some logic to prefer the 15-minutes one over the 5-minutes ones.

Comment: Also, how much of an overhead is it to use `DelayedQueue` for a single-threaded app? (You mentioned it's a concurrent queue)

Comment: And of course, thanks for all the help and responsiveness, erickson!

Comment: @Elimination I added some additional strategies to address your concerns about ordering. As far as the overhead, `DelayedQueue` uses a `PriorityQueue` internally, with a `ReentrantLock` for concurrency; for a concurrent collection, you can't do much better, and for throughput, the overhead of concurrency is worth it.

Comment: Thank you so much for all those ideas! I like the "grace period" but I'm not sure how to put it into practice. Especially when `DelayQueue` won't let me look ahead.

Comment: It is worth mentioning this module isn't responsible for the process of polling - it only queues them to other servers which do that.

Comment: @Elimination For the grace period, you wouldn't look ahead in the queue. Instead, the head of the queue would be unconditionally removed and inspected; a property on the element would indicate the grace period, and depending on that, execution would either continue, or the element would be discarded and the processor would look for the next element.

Comment: How about: Using a `PriorityQueue` (I could go single-threaded). Then, popping out `n` elements from the pqueue and applying some metric on them?

Comment: As far as I understand, if a grace period is applied, we remove the sensor,  set the new polling time to be `now + grace_period` and putting it back into the pqueue. What I don't understand is the logic for deciding if to apply it or not.

Comment: @Elimination Yes, you can do that too. You could loop; in an inner loop, peek at the queue, and pop any "ready" tasks into another priority queue, which is ordered by importance. Pop the head of the second queue and execute it, then loop back to the outer loop. That's basically the single-threaded version of the "do everything late" approach. Which you could modify to the "hybrid" approach if you weed out some tasks from the second queue of "ready" tasks.

Comment: @Elimination The grace period isn't necessarily the new polling time. The grace period simply tells you the time after which the task should be skipped instead of executed. For example, suppose the polling period is 1 minute. But if you are more than 45 seconds late, you'd rather just skip that sample in an effort to catch up. Then the grace period would be 45 seconds. If a task was dequeued 50 seconds after its scheduled time, it would be discarded, but a replacement might be scheduled for 10 seconds from now (hoping to be back on schedule by then). Whatever makes sense in your application.

Comment: @erickson, I get your intention now, though as my system operates, it's never too late to poll a sensor (when `now > time_to_poll`). I mean, if you passed `time_to_poll`, you better do it. Yet, if we combine the "importance" parameter then as you suggested, we may skip a sensor in favor of more important ones.

Answer (score 1):

The following could be the approaches to your problem :

1) If there is large variety of priorities you need to handle then using a single priority-queue is advisable. Basically you need to bump up the priority of low priority job to higher priority job after it waits for some time. This way you can handle the case when low priority jobs are starving indefinitely, but could temporarily starve high priority jobs if there are lots of low priority jobs.

2) When there are limited variety of priority jobs available then using multiple queues is advisable. Now each of these queue hold specific priority jobs. So for every job taken out of low priority-queue, you could poll multiple jobs out of higher priority queues. This helps in reducing the starving rate of lower priority jobs.